# Authenticating with Passport.JS using jQuery doesn't store cookies

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, passport.js

I have a frontend which is an [Electron app](https://electron.atom.io) and a backend written in Node.
When I hit login button my app sends Ajax POST request to my backend, which returns that authentication was successful. When I try to get if user is authenticated using `req.isAuthenticated()` I get `false`.
It could be because my frontend domain (`file://some/path/.../...`) differs from backend domain (`https://somewhere.on.georgenet.gq`) (These are just examples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Cookies` are not set when browsing using the `file:///` protocol. That's why `req.isAuthenticated()` returns `false`